# Wait for a button to disappear [Swift]

Tags: swift, xctest

I have a Swift function that checks for a button on my app to disappear before returning true:

```
func checkButton() -> Bool { return !self.appReference.buttons["ButtonA"].isHittable }
```

How do I continuously ping this function every x seconds until the result is true or a defined timeout expires. I'm new to Swift, but I could achieve the same objective in Java using Awaitility.

Something like

```
var counter = 0
while (counter < 20) {
   if (checkButton()) {break}
   sleep(2)
   counter++
}
if (counter == 20) throw Error
```

Does something more official/clean exist or is this how it's done in Swift?

Comment: Polling to wait for something is the worst choice. A better way is to make the button notify when it's going to disappear, or monitor the `isHidden` property with KVO or Combine.

Comment: @vadian this is helpful to know, ill look into these. If you have an example implementation, feel free to post as an answer

Comment: An example requires more information about the button logic and at least which platform you are talking about.

Comment: I’m using the XC UI Test platform (SwiftUI buttons)